# How to create custom email verification in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I am trying to make custom email verification after new users registered on my page.
I´ve started with adding middleware group inside my web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','verified']], function() {
     //my routes
}
```

Than I created and registered my custom middleware for veryfi users

```
class WereEmailVerified
{
   
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->verified == True)
        {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return response()->json('No ACCESS! Verif your email first');
    }
}
```

Than I´ve added logic after succefull registration of user it should dispatch event

```
 public function create_new_user(Array $attributes)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();

        try {
            $user = User::create($attributes);
            DB::commit();
            event(new Registered($user));

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            dd($e);
            DB::rollBack();

            throw $e;
        }
    }
```

But the error has occured:

```
"Route [verification.verify] not defined."
```

I tried to look for what I am missing but I don´t really know how to solve this. If you can help me I will be very thankfull...

Comment: where are you calling for the route `verification.verify` in your views ?

Comment: Nowhere I thinked it has been called in             ```event(new Registered($user));```
; becouse this errror is throven as an  Exception

Comment: Why not just use [Fortify](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify) which has all this logic baked in?

Comment: define any dummy route as `verification.verify` to rule out that case.